# Cannot start debuggiing Azure Function on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019, azure-functions-core-tools

I cannot start debuggiing Azure Function on Visual Studio 2019.
When I start it, showing window message `パスに無効な文字が含まれています`
(`The path contains invalid characters`)
Difficultily I can build Azure Function Project(C#) and debug console not showing error message
Because I cannot conitinue develop , I want help me...
I didn't find information about it on the Internet .
Most simply cs project even occur such error. Azure Function is v3. NET.Sdk.Functions is Version3.0.9. The matter occuered after the PC shutted down during Azure Function Surver on localhost was working on debugging. tried to reinstall VisIual Studio and Update but I cannot get good results

Comment: Most simply cs project even occur such error. Azure Function is v3. NET.Sdk.Functions is Version3.0.9. The matter occuered after the PC shutted down during Azure Function Surver on localhost was working on debugging.  tried to reinstall VisIual Studio and Update but I cannot get good results.

Comment: @mounntainn Please edit your question when adding more information, even if you respond in comments as well. Make the question concise and explain both what you expected to happen, what steps you took, and then what happened that you didn't expect. Include the minimal amount of code someone would need to be able to reproduce the same problem. This will make the question better and give the best possibility of getting a answer.